# Can I open a route I created in Google Maps in Navigation?

Tags: gps, navigation, google-maps-navigation, maps

I'd love to be able to open that map on my phone in such a way that I can get turn-by-turn navigation, like what is available in the Navigation app.

However, despite my experiments, this seems to be impossible. I would have thought Navigation and Maps would be based on the same formats and code, but there appears to be a wall between them.

Is there any way I can create, edit, and save a map on the Desktop, and then have it viewable on my phone for turn-by-turn navigation?

The key is that I use this for biking, and I can not see my phone while I'm riding. So I want to have an earpiece and be able to hear instructions for turns.

Comment: See http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8499/gps-app-to-follow-a-prepared-itinerary for suggestions

Comment: Thanks, but that guy seems to have slightly different issues. He needs offline (I don't), he needs to work in Android 1.5 (I have 2.2), and I must admit, I'm a little confused by the suggested apps. Are they supposed to supplant Google Maps or Navigator? I don't clearly see how they would open or use maps I create in Google Maps on my desktop.

Comment: Have you tried [Chrome-to-Phone](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chrometophone)?

Comment: No, but I'll try it and see what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps for Android does have a bicycle option.  You just have to select it from the drop down menu.

[image]

Comment: Your interface is different from mine. I don't know how to take a screenshot of my phone, but mine (version 5.5.0) has a search box, and three icons along the top (one is for "Places", one is for layers, and one is to get my current location). I don't have the Maps and Navigation icon like you do. What do I do to get your interface?
(Also, while I appreciate this answer, I would still like to be able to import created routes, so I couldn't call this a direct answer to my question.)

Answer (score 1):

First login to your Google account in desktop and open Google maps find the route you want to drive and to your left you can see save to my maps click it and save it in your google account

Then open your Google maps in your Android mobile in options you can see My places options click on it (assuming you have internet connection) the route will be opened in your map you can select get driving directions from there and it will be loaded in your Android maps ;) cheers ..........

Comment: This navigates from your current location to the start/end that you choose.

Comment: This works for me on 4.0.3

Comment: I have the same experience as @cjk. This method will take a saved location, and then determine a route to that location from one's current location. This is not the same has plotting a whole route, and then being able to follow that route, which is what is hoped for in the question.